# What does the error message 'Not all arguments converted during string formatting' mean?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

Why do I get an error message?

my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g, request, url_for
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.database = 'cc.db'

def connect_db():
   return sqlite3.connect(app.database)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    posts = "0"
    if request.method =='POST':
        name = request.form['nm']
        g.db = connect_db()
        cur = g.db.execute('SELECT * FROM sols WHERE name LIKE '%'', str(name,))
        posts = [dict(name=row[0], color=row[1], size=row[2], location=row[3]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
        g.db.close()

    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm trying to do an autocomplete function with jquery. First of all I need to access the db. I can't figure out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got your quoting wrong. The following is **not** one string:

```
'SELECT * FROM sols WHERE name LIKE '%''
```

That's two strings separated by the `%` operator.

You are asking Python to use the `%` operator on `'SELECT * FROM sols WHERE name LIKE '`, and `%` on strings executes a *string interpolation*. Since there are no place holders to interpolate *into*, but you do have 1 value to interpolate (the empty string), you get your error.

You would need to use *double* quotes or escape the embedded quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM sols WHERE name LIKE '%'"
```

However, now you don't have a SQL parameter placeholder. You'd have to add your `%` wildcard to the value and use a placeholder like this:

```
cur = g.db.execute('SELECT * FROM sols WHERE name LIKE ?', (name + '%',))
```

Here the `?` will be replaced by the first parameter, which is set to the `name` parameter with a `%` SQL wildcard appended on. The database driver will take care of properly quoting that string.

Comment: or use string escaping: 
    'SELECT * FROM sols WHERE name LIKE \'%\' '

Comment: @horst666: *or escape the embedded quotes*.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps me !